# All times with a specified date in Deedle F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-data, deedle

I have CSVs with OHLC and DateTime data, the data is sampled with 1 minute bars and I want to calculate the VWAP for different time frames. How can I index into a frame to get all the times within a specific day?

```
let csv_temp = Frame.ReadCsv<DateTime>(filepath, indexCol ="Date and Time")
```

then

```
(csv_temp?Close * csv_temp?Volume)
```

which gives me:

```
1/2/2013 9:31:00 AM  -> 65088       
1/2/2013 9:32:00 AM  -> 4432997.7   
1/2/2013 9:33:00 AM  -> 1407412.375 
1/2/2013 9:34:00 AM  -> 918077      
1/2/2013 9:35:00 AM  -> 1037200.32  
1/2/2013 9:36:00 AM  -> 1464104.6   
1/2/2013 9:37:00 AM  -> 1179067.16  
1/2/2013 9:38:00 AM  -> 1416311.45  
1/2/2013 9:39:00 AM  -> 1893821.16  
1/2/2013 9:40:00 AM  -> 521449.4442 
1/2/2013 9:41:00 AM  -> 656896.779  
1/2/2013 9:42:00 AM  -> 518200.425  
1/2/2013 9:43:00 AM  -> 1327152.28  
1/2/2013 9:44:00 AM  -> 1035047.64  
1/2/2013 9:45:00 AM  -> 1133165.55  
...                  -> ...         
4/10/2015 3:46:00 PM -> 1284412.341 
4/10/2015 3:47:00 PM -> 900809.43   
4/10/2015 3:48:00 PM -> 542263.54   
4/10/2015 3:49:00 PM -> 393960.84   
4/10/2015 3:50:00 PM -> 1395440.96  
4/10/2015 3:51:00 PM -> 1927824.3   
4/10/2015 3:52:00 PM -> 1458494.1   
4/10/2015 3:53:00 PM -> 1092189.57  
4/10/2015 3:54:00 PM -> 1675165.38  
4/10/2015 3:55:00 PM -> 987443.275  
4/10/2015 3:56:00 PM -> 1519896.625 
4/10/2015 3:57:00 PM -> 1100833.68  
4/10/2015 3:58:00 PM -> 1216154.3   
4/10/2015 3:59:00 PM -> 1648792.64  
4/10/2015 4:00:00 PM -> 5523283.36
```

I will like to have something like:

```
(csv_temp?Close * csv_temp?Volume).GetRowsWith(DateTime(2013,1,2))
```

Then chunk into the data with different timespans to calculate the averages?

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar with deedle but i was curious and found this
http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/tutorial.html

based on that i would try:

```
let dateTimeFilter = [ ... ] //todo add the dateTimes that are currently of interest
// in the tutorial it was like this [ for d in 2 .. 4 -> DateTime(2013, 1, d) ]

let filtered = csv_temp.Rows.[dateTimeFilter]

let result = (filtered?Close * filtered?Volume) |> Stats.mean
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the CSV-file you're using, so I haven't tried this out. But you should be able to do something like `(filtered?Close * filtered?Volume) |> Series.groupInto (fun k _ -> k.Date) (fun _ group -> Stats.mean group)`.

This will calculate the `close*volume` for each minute, then group these by the `Date`-part (i.e. by day) and finally, for each day, find the mean value.